# Django Filter: "Sort By" Feature

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I want to sort the products based on boolean field "is_featured", date creation, and price.

My goal:
[This is what i want to achieve. Images shows a website that I am taking ideas from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qor4q.png)

I currently have a checkbox filter (implemented through django-filter) for users to filter based on brand and category. You can see my "draft" here https://ecommercelsm.herokuapp.com/product/

I want to add a sort_by dropdown menu like the one in the attached image so that users can sort the orders of the products by featured, price or date creation after filtering or without.
I do not know how to go about this. Can someone help? I feel like i need to add more fields to my ProductFilter.

**models.py**

```
class Product(MPTTModel):

    bool_choices = (
        (True, 'Yes'),
        (False, 'No'),
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',  blank = True, null = True, related_name = 'children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=False)
    category = TreeManyToManyField(Category, blank = True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product") 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(blank = True, upload_to = 'images/')
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(choices=bool_choices)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'product'

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Category(MPTTModel):
    bool_choices = (
        (True, 'Yes'),
        (False, 'No'),
    )
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',  blank = True, null = True, related_name = 'children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'categories'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
```

**filters.py**

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    brand = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    category = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Product 
        fields = ('brand','category') 

    def __init__(self, products= "", category=Category.objects.none(),*args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['brand'].queryset = Brand.objects.filter(product__in=products).distinct()  
        self.filters['category'].queryset = category
```

Comment: In Django, this is called [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) (taking its terminology from SQL); `order_by` is a method of a `QuerySet`.

Answer (score -1):

Try the [Django Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html) package. For your use case you could try to play with the different widgets.

**EDIT

This SO [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726759/dropdown-select-option-to-filter-a-django-list) is explaining what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think what i need to do is create a dropdown menu that combines fields of is_featured, price and created_at .